# A type with finite number of elements - OCaml

Tags: types, functional-programming, ocaml, c-intermediate-language

I'm using CIL to process C programs using the pthread library. I have to process user-defined and non-pthread functions differently from pthread functions. Can I have a type definition which looks something like:

```
type PThreadFun = "pthread_create" | "pthread_join" | ...;;
```

so that I first pattern-match on the function name and then send it to either

```
processFunction (fn_name: string)
```

or

```
processPThreadFun (fn_name: PThreadFun)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can have [sum types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) in OCaml, they are called [variants](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/coreexamples.html#sec11). But their values are not strings. You could declare

```
type pthreadfun_t = Pthread_create | Pthread_join (* etc *);
```

<sup>Then you'll need some code processing the CIL representation to find such `pthreadfun_t` values.</sup>

BTW, you might be interested by [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), which is a domain specific language to extend the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler. MELT works on the internal GCC representations, notably [Gimple](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html). It is not Ocaml or CIL based, but it is a GCC plugin giving you a powerful Lisp-like domain specific language with powerful **pattern-matching**, including ability to match Gimple-s, Tree-s, strings, etc...